# how to change the build directory of opencv

Tags: macos, opencv, path, cmake

I'm trying to install opencv on MacOS 10.12. The original build path is

```html
/Users/niceycb/opencv/build
```

But I deleted it incautiously，when I use the cmake command again, the build path turns into

```html
/Users/niceycb/.Trash/build
```

Though I tried to reedit the CMakeCache.txt, it didn't work

Comment: *Build directory* is one from which `cmake` is called. (If you use GUI, build directory can be explicitely set).

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)  After using CMake-GUI, the cvconfig.h is in /Users/niceycb/opencv/build, but when I use command $ make on terminal, the output is different from the CMake-GUI output. For example, cvconfig.h is in:/Users/niceycb/.Trash/build, also, Libraries,numpy,packages path of Python 2 disappeared.